# JS regex exclude http only - https must be included

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I need to use Javascript to validate URL input, where all URLs except insecure http protocol are valid.

Example of valid URLs:

```
https://example.com/
https://example.com/path
application://example.com/path
application://example
```

Example of invalid URL:

```
http:\\example.com
```

I've tried negative lookahead, but it doesn't work:

```
^(?!http[s]{0}).*:\/\/.*$
```

How to write regex, which will exclude http protocol only (other protocols e.g. https must be included)?

Comment: How is it known if `application://example.com/path` is secure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use it like this:

```
^(?!http:)[^:]+:\/\/.+$
```

`(?!http:)` is negative lookahead to fail the match if string starts with `http:` thus failing the match for `http://...` URLs.

However do note that this regex doesn't do complex URL validation, it just takes care of failing the match for `http:` URLs/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `URL api` and match the `protocol` property with `http:`

```js
let urlTester = (url) => {
  let urlParsed = new URL(url)
  return urlParsed.protocol !== 'http:'
}

console.log(urlTester('https://example.com/'))
console.log(urlTester('https://example.com/path'))
console.log(urlTester('application://example.com/path'))
console.log(urlTester('application://example'))
console.log(urlTester('http://example.com'))
```